# Model is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I've read a lot of similar posts about null model but my case is very very simple and still the model on Create action is null. What am I doing wrong???

Here is the situation: One main view, two strongly typed partial views inside, each binded to a public property of the main model. Any help is appreciated.
**models**:

```
public class SimpleModel1
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SomeStrings1 { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleModel2
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SomeStrings2 { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexModel
{
    public SimpleModel1 model1 { get; set; }
    public SimpleModel2 model2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SomeStringsComplex { get; set; }
}
```

int he **controller**:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ComplexModel complex = new ComplexModel();
        complex.model1 = new SimpleModel1();
        complex.model1.SomeStrings1 = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3"};

        complex.model2 = new SimpleModel2();
        complex.model2.SomeStrings2 = new List<string> { "b1", "b2", "b3" };

        complex.SomeStringsComplex = new List<string> { "c1", "c2", "c3" };
        return View(complex);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ComplexModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var test = model.SomeStringsComplex;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Views**:
2 strong partial views -each for model

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"     
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApp1.Models.SimpleModel2>" %>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <% foreach (string item in Model.SomeStrings2)
            {%>
            <p>
            <label for="Title">Item Title:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox(item,item)%>               
            </p>
            <%
            }
         %>
</fieldset>
```

1 main view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApp1.Models.ComplexModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
 Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Create</h2>
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
 <fieldset>
<div> Own values
<% foreach (string item in Model.SomeStringsComplex)
            {%>
            <p>
            <label for="Title">Item Title:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox(item,item) %>          
            </p>
            <%
            }
         %>
</div>
<div>Simple values 1
<%Html.RenderPartial("SimpleModelView1", this.ViewData.Model.model1, new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
</div>

<div>Simple values 2
<%Html.RenderPartial("SimpleModelView2", Model.model2, new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
</div>
<p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: Are you saying you get a `NullReferenceException` at `var test = model.SomeStringsComplex;` because `model` is null?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 : I think he was, and I think it was happening because he wasn't sending anything into the view: `return View();` , but OP never commented on that.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'm going to take a wild stab and say your Model validation is failing when posting a ComplexModel back to the server</strike>

Your Model validation doesn't have to fail at all. You're not returning anything from inside the `if` block so you're always returning a View with no Model associated:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var test = model.SomeStringsComplex;
}
return View(); // View is called with no Model data
```

Judging by your code, that would cause the Create view to be instantiated with no Model. That can be fixed fairly simply:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ComplexModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var test = model.SomeStringsComplex;
        // Do something to Create the object

        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Model State is invalid, return so the user can correct
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: the create view shows data correctly but when posted - the model is null

Comment: +1 good point about not returning anything if `ModelState.IsValid` is `true`.  Shouldn't this generate an error, "not all code paths return a value"?

Comment: @adrift - No...in the original example no matter what happened the code would fall through the if statement and return View();

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you supposed to send something to the view, on that line?

```
return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are specifying your text fields - the model binder does not know how to assign them back to the properties that they came from.

You may want to read this Haacked article that describes how to use model binding for enumerable properties:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: there is some point in that - but I changed all the IEnumerable props in all the models with simple int and the only value that is not null in the post back action is the int of the ComplexModel - the simple models nested are still null.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. The data posted to Create method should look s.th. like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ComplexModel mainModel, SimpleModel nestedModel, SimpleModel2 nested2Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var main = mainModel;
        var nested1 = nestedModel;
        var nested2 = nested2Model;
    }

    return View();
}
```

The nested parameters are not null when the models are binded to partial views. If used in the main form through main model than the values are in the instance of the main model. I've also changed `IEnumerable<string>` to `IList<string>` and then rendered the string values with

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Strings.Count; i++)
{ %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.Strings[i])%>
<% }
```

Thanks all